# How do I set screen size using winbgi? (without graphics.h, winbgim, but pure winbgi)

Tags: c++, bgi

How do I set window size using winbgi?

Default window size is left half of my screen=
[Complile result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQBzT.png)

MY professor wants me to 'only' use winbgi

```
WinBGI& win = WinBGI::instance();
// then what??
```

winbgi does not include initwindow() that can set window size

```
int initwindow (int width, int height, const char* title="Windows BGI", int left=0, int top=0, bool dbflag=false, bool closeflag=true);
```

I've looked up the documention and I couldn't find one

[bgi](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/doc/index.html)

I want to set BGI window size (height, width)

I am using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: "MY professor wants me to 'only' use winbgi" - But *Why*?

Answer (score 0):

Man, the education system is weird when your professors want you to use an extremely outdated version of a graphics library.

Comment: What do you mean? I used BGI in '89, that's not that long ago.... (of course Borland was a DOS IDE at the time)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Man, satire is great.